# Select an Audio File from File System

Tags: codenameone

I am writing an APP to send an Audio file from the device to a web-service, 
i can write the web-service part.

How do I open a dialog to select the audio file from the list of audio files on the device, and pass the location to the web-service?

Michael

Answer (score 1):

There is no native API for picking an audio file on devices.

Devices have the ability to pick images/photos but not arbitrary files like audio files.

Check out the new [file chooser](https://github.com/shannah/cn1-filechooser) cn1lib that's available in the extensions menu.